# Подпись запроса при валидации apple pay c backend PHP

Tags: php, curl, opencart, apple

Ситуация такая
Apple Pay и tinkoff
После создания платежной сессии

```
var request = {
            countryCode: 'RU',
            currencyCode: 'RUB',
            supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard'],
            merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
            total: { label: 'julianikolenko', amount: amount_rub },
        };
var session = new ApplePaySession(3, request);
```

Определяется метод session.onvalidatemerchant  который отправляет validationURL на backend сайта. С backend  необходимо обратиться по адресу переданному в validationURL

apple:

> Your server uses the validation URL to request a session from the Apple Pay server, as described in Requesting an Apple Pay Payment Session.

В итоге есть

validationURL на который надо отправить запрос
merchant_id.cer - сертификат полученный в developer.apple.com
и данные о магазине

Как это сделать? backend на php
Пробовал curl не пойму как правильно составить запрос

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    $args = [];
    $args['merchantIdentifier'] = '______';
    $args['displayName'] = '_____';
    $args['domainName'] = '____';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['appleValidationUrl']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, dirname(__FILE__)."/merchant_id.cer");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, dirname(__FILE__)."/merchant_id.cer");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);

    if($out === false)
    {
        $out = curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
```

Магазин сделан на OpenCart поэтому только php

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['appleValidationUrl']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, dirname(__FILE__)."/ApplePay.crt.pem");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, dirname(__FILE__)."/ApplePay.key.pem");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, "0258");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Как сделать сертификат 
https://github.com/norfolkmustard/ApplePayJS